# Bogus Results from Simple Assembly Program on FreeBSD System

Tags: linux, assembly, compatibility, freebsd, gnu-assembler

I've been having problems getting even the simplest of assembly programs that I write on Linux to run on my FreeBSD machine. Here's the offending code (I'm trying to keep this as simple as possible):

```
#counts to sixty
 .section .data
 .section .text
 .global _start
_start:
 movl $1, %ecx           #move $1 into ecx
 movl $1, %eax
start_loop:
 addl %ecx, %eax        #add ecx to eax
 cmpl $60, %eax         #compare $60 and eax...
  je end_loop            #if eax = 60 go to end_loop
 cmpl $60, %eax #
  jle start_loop         #jump if eax is < $60...
  jmp start_loop         #...to start_loop

 end_loop:
  movl %eax, %ebx        #move the value of eax into ebx because ebx holds
                         #the return value
  movb $1, %al           #Move $1 into eax (int 1 is the value for the 
                         #exit() syscall
  int $0x80
```

The Linux machine returns the expected resulted which is sixty, whereas the FreeBSD machine consistently returns 164 for the return code. Does anybody know why this is? If so, can you please explain to me what is happening? Also, I should mention that they are both indeed running x86 CPUs. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the [FreeBSD Developer's handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/x86-system-calls.html), and you need to do:

```
push %eax
mov $1, %eax
push %eax
int $0x80
```

because:

1. only the system call vector is passed via register `%eax`, all arguments are on the stack
2. the FreeBSD default syscall expects an additional word on the stack, which would be a dummy for inlined uses of `int $0x80` but a return address where you do a syscall via a `call kernel_entry` trampoline (that then can do `int $0x80; ret`).

If you want to use the Linux convention (some syscall args in regs, called "Alternative Calling convention" in the manual), you have to brand the executable so that the system knows you're using Linux-style syscalls.